# Solr nodes go down after each other

Tags: solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to re-index my solr index but solr datacenter goes down after in a while. I cannot get it re-indexed. When I look at the log files, I see nothing.

I have 4 nodes 1 Cassandra datacenter and 4 nodes 1 Solr datacenter. The column family has 400M row. I cannot figure out, Do I need new nodes, reduce rows count or something else.

I also tried to follow recommended settings. Is there anything to help?

Comment: You are probably running out of memory on the nodes and are getting hit by the OS OOM killer. Can you look in /var/log either syslog or messages for any host kernel: Out of Memory: Killed process type messages.

Comment: There are a ton of factors that can contribute. As Mike stated it could be an OOM of some sort. Check the system.log but also what's your hardware? Are you on spinning disks? What about your text chain? Do you have a lot of analyzers in your chain? Also what's your index size? Are you maybe running out of space on your disks?

Comment: @mikea I cannot see "Out of Memory" logs in /var/log/syslog in my solr nodes. I used to set 14GB heap size before seeing nodes down. Now, I set heap size 24GB heap size in solr nodes.
Then, going down nodes number is decreased. But still  it happens. I am not able to perform re-index or remove node without going down nodes. It is bothering being not able to perform
operations such as re-index, repair without troubles.

I have 32GB ram, 6 core machine with 2 threads per core, one ssd for commitlogs, one 3TB spinning disk for data and index. My text length in column it is not much.

Comment: What's the data density per node like? 6 core, 32 GB RAM and Spinning disks is on the low side for Solr. That being said, When you do a reindex, all that data has to go through the indexing path. Spinning disks usually can't keep up with that - or very well at least. I'm assuming there's a bit of IO contention going on. What does nodetool tpstats tell you? Anything blocked there? Which version of DSE are you using? 24GB heap will only help if you are using the G1GC (Default in DSE 4.8).

Comment: @MarcintheCloud the data is written in 7 months. Nodetool tpstats tells me that there is  pending compaction around 200~300 and  dropped message  in mutation stage.